# Do I need a pancake box to hang a ceiling fan or can I use what is already in the ceiling?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, joists

I have a space in the ceiling that looks to be wired for a ceiling fan.  It had a plastic cover over it.  I did notice that the cover was screwed into wood that I assuming those are the joists.  I didn't see any other areas that I could screw in the ceiling fan bracket. Would a pancake box work and then just hang the ceiling fan bracket off of that?   It's hard to tell (for me) what is going on in the picture.  Thanks[image]

Comment: Can you pull the wires out so they aren't in the way and then get us *clear* photos of the back of the box please?  (I suspect it could be fan rated, but am not sure.)

Answer (score 2):

Try to pull the wires out a little more and check the writing on the box. It should tell you if it's ceiling fan rated. Even if it is, it's always good to remove a few screws and make sure it's mounted securely to joists. If it's not rated for a ceiling fan, you'll have to replace it with pancake box or some other ceiling fan rated box. Make sure the power is off before doing any work. Even though you have the wires nutted, you'll need to remove the wire nuts to replace the box. I've seen people get knocked on their butt because they forgot to turn off the power before removing the wire nuts.

Comment: And if you happen to be on a ladder when you hit live wires, your butt may end up on the floor several feet down adding injury to injury.